# Export photos from iPad or Apple TV

Tags: ipad, photos.app, appletv

I have a lot of photos in which I have tagged people, given it the right information and so on. Sadly, I lost all these photos when I did a clean install of OS X Lion. The photos were being synchronized to my iPad and my Apple TV and therefore I have the photos on both of those devices with faces and all the correct information.

Does anyone know of a way to extract the photos with all the information (especially the faces) from the iPad or the Apple TV and into iPhoto?

Answer (score 1):

This is untested but two options spring to mind:

1. Use iPhoto on iPad to transfer to iTunes (Not free as you need to buy iOS iPhoto)
   There's an option to share/save the photos to iTunes. You might need to make an album first and add the photos.
2. Make a new photostream on your iPad, add all the photos. Open up iPhoto on mac and copy them across from this photostream.

Answer (score 0):

There should be free ways to do it too, but i've used [phone to mac](http://www.macroplant.com/phonetomac/)  (25 $) and know - it works :-) Transfers music, videos, photos and more back to your mac.

Comment: I just bought and tried it out. It's better than nothing. I'm able to recover all my photos from my iPad but it doesn't transfer data for "Faces". All my photos tagged with faces are just plain albums. E.g. if I have tagged "John Doe" on twenty photos, these photos will just be in an album named "John Doe" and will not appear in Faces in iPhoto.